# pygame - how to change an image/blit over previous one?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm pretty new to coding. I was thrown straight into it by my (terrible) programming teacher. This is what I've got:

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Caldun")

bg = pygame.image.load("Background.png")
bg2 = pygame.image.load("BG2 clone.png")
bg3 = pygame.image.load("BG2 clone clone.png")


white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Press Start 2P", 23)
label = myfont.render("Welcome to the land of Caldun.", 1, (255,255,255))
label2 = myfont.render("Click to continue", 1, (255,255,255))


running = 1

while running:
    screen.fill((black))
    screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
    screen.blit(bg3,(37,30))
    screen.blit(label, (65,420))
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or \
        (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and
        (event.key == K_ESCAPE)):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if(event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and
            (event.key == K_SPACE)):
            screen.blit(bg2,(37,30))
            pygame.display.update()
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so that when you press spacebar, it will blit bg2 over bg3, and basically remove bg3 from the screen. For some reason, this isn't working out for me. What happens is that the screen kind of just flashes and shows bg2 for only a split second. I do realize that I have two pygame.display.update()s, and this is probably causing it, but I'm pretty lost. I'd appreciate it if I could get some pointers on what to do, or even how to clean up my code and where to go with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've rewritten your main loop as follows to resolve the issue:

```
running = True
stage = 1

while running:

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (65, 420))

    if stage == 1:
        screen.blit(bg2, (37, 30))
    else:
        screen.blit(bg3, (37, 30))        

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT or \
                (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
            stage += 1
```

The problem with your existing code is that it assumes the `KEYDOWN` event is sticky, that is it is reported each loop iterations while the key is held down, but this is not the case. To resolve this we use the `stage` variable to track the current state you want to display and update it whenever the space key is pressed.

As per you comment I've updated the code so you could use it to present a simple sequence. To add additional stages in the sequence just update the `stage` if test to support additional values, e.g:

```
if state == 1:
    ...render graphics for stage 1

elif state == 2:
    ...render graphics for stage 2

elif state == n:
    ...render graphics for stage `n`

else:
    ...render the final stage graphics
```

Comment: This seems to work better, and thank you for that - but I probably should have clarified myself a bit more. What I want to show up is, when you press spacebar, it should permanently change the image to bg2, and not only when you're holding it down. It's supposed to also be so that another text box replaces the old one, kinda like a story sequence.

Comment: Hi @DuckInvaders - I've updated the code so that is supports a simple sequence and provide guidance on how to extend this to support more stages - hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for! You're wonderful.

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer which helped most in solving the problem as accepted - [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).